# Webpack multiple output locations for different static file types

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Background:**

Is there a way for me to output files into a directory structure like so:

```
|-- dist
    |-- js
    |-- css
    |-- img
    |-- index.html
```

Currently my `webpack.config.js` output looks like:

```
output: {
    filename: '[name]-[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
  },
```

Since all my files currently appear in the dist folder unorganized, I currently use gulp to move my files into the more readable directory structure above. The problem is that **when I do this manual move, it breaks all the references in code ([name].bundle.js) so the assests don't load**.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('clean-logs', () =>
  gulp.src('./logs/*.log', {
    read: false,
  }).pipe(clean()));

// Take all static files in the /dist directory
// and organize them into folders based on type
gulp.task('organize-dist-static-files', () => {
  gulp.src('./dist/*.{png,gif,jpg,jpeg,svg}')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/img'));
  gulp.src('./dist/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/js'));
  gulp.src('./dist/*.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/css'));
  gulp.src('./dist/*.{woff,woff2,eot,ttf,otf}')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('clean-original-dist-files', () => {
  // remove files from original locations
  gulp.src('./dist/*.{png,gif,jpg,jpeg,svg,js,css,woff,woff2,eot,ttf,otf}', {
    read: false,
  }).pipe(clean());
});
```

**Question:**

**Is there a way I can organize webpack to automatically configure the output file references in a way that matches the above directory structure so that the references are still valid?**

Comment: question: why? This is production build which is not supposed to be human friendly

Comment: just don't want it to be a giant mess.

Comment: just accept it and be happy. You can configure it differently, no doubts webpack can definitely do it, however introducing another layer of complexity into the thing that you / your user never sees just because you personally do not like it might be not a good idea. Webpack does it like that; there is no real reason to make it different. If you still want it - here you go https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

Comment: yeah good point mate. I'll just go with webpack's default config for now but thanks for the reference just in case I decide to pursue that route. Much appreciated

Comment: np, btw you can wrap your gulp implementation into a custom webpack plugin if you want (just for fun of course) and achieve it in kinda webpack way. But this is some sort of interesting thing to try, still this isn't going to give any value apart from the experience :)

Comment: oh that would be something to try if I have more time :) but if it isn't going to add any value then there isn't much point like you mentioned.